# Why static class

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Why do you use the class with only static members?
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/common/core/editOperation.ts#L11

What benefits does it make?

Why do not use flat code structure? Like this:
https://gist.github.com/DScheglov/f2a509498c035a1f0ec38fbcf895fd1e

Comment: I guess it's mostly a matter of preference. Or maybe they're planning ahead for possible interfaces / non-static method

Comment: maybe the authors of the class with only static members are not used to writing javascript and come from a language where it's the only option.

Comment: because that's what happen when you have a language that allow you to accomplish the same thing in multiple ways?

Comment: In this case the class functions as a container/namespace for the functions. In plain old javascript you could put your functions inside a named object to group them.

Comment: @Evert, I think so too, ... but it is a code by Microsoft.